# Timeout of OracleDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, fill

In my application written in C# I use `OracleDataAdapter.Fill()` for fetching data from oracle database. Is there a way to set a timeout for executing this method, because sometimes it is stucked forever?

UPDATE:  Instead of "System.Data.OracleClient;" I used "Oracle.DataAccess.Client;" and then code below works good.

```
using Oracle.DataAcces.Client;
...
OracleDataAdapter yourAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQLString, connection);
yourAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=120;
yourAdapter.fill(yourDataSet);
```

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. This question asks how to set a timeout and the other question asks how to solve a timeout error?

Comment: It's not the same question, similar but not the same. The answer on that other question did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    OracleDataAdapter yourAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQLString, connection);
    yourAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=120;
   yourAdapter.fill(yourDataSet);
```

check the [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwis67Grt7fHAhXCW44KHYtmBKA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=OanVVezqKcK3uQSLzZGACg&usg=AFQjCNGVO_tOsMkEil0B3xQ3aNZ1EN7yQw&cad=rja) for knowing more about commandtimeout

Comment: I cannot asign any number to commandtimeout. even if i do this 
yourAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=120;
after this command CommandTimeout is still zero, and that means no time limit

Comment: what do you mean cannot assign number?are you getting any error?

Comment: No, there is no error. It executes without any errors but the value of CommandTimeout is not changed, it is always zero (before and after assignment).

Comment: check this [link](https://community.oracle.com/message/1025399) to get a complete understanding of commandtimeout. your question helped me to understand a concept.thanks..

Comment: Thank you. This one solved my problem. Instead of "System.Data.OracleClient;" I used "Oracle.DataAccess.Client;" and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `OracleDataAdapter` (as every class derived from the [DbDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) base class) has a `SelectCommand` used to retrieve the data to insert in the target DataSet, this SelectCommand has a property named `CommandTimeout` that you can set to a time in seconds to raise the Timeout exception

[See MSDN DbCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)